# Is it possible to have hyphenations in \underlined{text}?

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, text-decorations

In a document I was writing, I had some really long captions and I wanted to emphasize the important parts in them. I tried to use `\underline{}` but no hyphenation was used at both the caption and at the list of figures. So I switched to `\textbf{}`.

So, as the title states, is it possible to have hyphenations in underlined text? If not, why is that so?

Comment: Usually text is emphasized with italics. Underlining is not a recommended practice in good typography.

Comment: @egreg: I know, it was not my choice though. At the end I used boldface. But I found it peculiar. So I asked :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Herbert was implying, it's not possible with `\underline{}`, use either the package `soul` and its `\ul{foo}` command, or the package `ulem`, which changes `\emph{foo}` to use underlining. There's more information on hyphenating underlined text on the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html):

> Knuth made no provision for underlining text: he took the view that
> underlining is not a typesetting operation, but rather one that
> provides emphasis on typewriters, which typically offer but one
> typeface. The corresponding technique in typeset text is to switch
> from upright to italic text (or vice-versa): the LaTeX command `\emph`
> does just that to its argument.
>
> Nevertheless, typographically illiterate people (such as those that
> specify double-spaced [thesis styles](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linespace)) continue to require underlining
> of us, so LaTeX as distributed defines an `\underline` command that
> applies the mathematical ‘underbar’ operation to text. This technique
> is not entirely satisfactory, however: the text gets stuck into a box,
> and won’t break at line end.
>
> Two packages are available that solve this problem. The *ulem* package
> redefines the `\emph` command to underline its argument; the underlined
> text thus produced behaves as ordinary emphasised text, and will break
> over the end of a line. (The package is capable of other peculiar
> effects, too: read its documentation, contained within the file
> itself.) The *soul* package defines an `\ul` command (after which the
> package is, in part, named) that underlines running text.
>
> Beware of *ulem*’s default behaviour, which is to convert the `\emph`
> command into an underlining command; this can be avoided by loading
> the package with:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
> ```
>
> Documentation of *ulem* is in the package itself.

(https://texfaq.org/FAQ-underline)

I can only second that: If you know why you want to use underlining, go ahead; but if not, consider another way of emphasizing your text.

Comment: documentation of ulem has been separated out, and is available in pdf form, like that of most other packages.  (it's probably still in the package, that being the no-effort alternative...)

Comment: @anon: Thanks for pointing out! You can notify the maintainers of the TeX FAQ at faq-devel@tex.ac.uk (http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=noans+newans).

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{0.8\textwidth} foo \ul{hyphenation} bar

\end{document}
```

[image]