# Closer underline

Tags: formatting, text-decorations

I am currently using `\underline{...}` to underline text.

However, I want the underline to be closer to the letters (as of now, there's too much whitespace between the letters and the line).  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I try to use \ul{български} - with cyrillic letters under utf8 but it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NikolayKirov I converted the non-answer to a comment. Perhaps consider to post a fresh question.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

`\underline{<stuff>}` underlines a box containing `<stuff>`. However, this also implies that `<stuff>` with descenders pushes the underline lower. `\smash{<stuff>}` removes any depth (and height) from `<stuff>`, allowing for the regular non-descender depth of the underline:

```
\underline{\smash{<stuff>}}
```

Alternatively, the [`soul` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/soul) provides underlining features. Here's a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\usepackage{soul}% http://ctan.org/pkg/soul
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. \par
\underline{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.} \par
\underline{\smash{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.}}

\setul{5pt}{.4pt}% 5pt below contents
\ul{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.} \par
\setul{1pt}{.4pt}% 1pt below contents
\ul{The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.} \par
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

See the [`soul` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf) (section **4 Underlining**, p 11 onward) for more information regarding settings and underlining control.

Comment: `soul`'s also recommendable because [it allows for hyphenation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31566/4012), as opposed to `\underline`. All apart from the fact that underlining is usually frowned upon as a remnant of typewriter "typography".

Comment: Is there a way to determine the default underline spacing with regards to \setul?  For example, I want to \setul{5pt}{.4pt} for one paragraph and then return to the default for the next paragraph.  Is there a way to do this without trial and error?

Comment: Ah, never mind.  The \resetul command does what I need.  (It doesn't tell me what the default spacing is, but I guess I don't really need that.)

Comment: Thanks! This works beautifully. I am also stumped that only after 12 years of intensive latex use this is my first time using underline. Heh?