# Scots-Irish American surnames: How to achieve aesthetically appealing raised-c with macron (Mc)?

Tags: macron

My last name is McAnulty. There are a variety of pronunciations such as Mick-Uh-Nulty, Mick-Nulty, and Mack-Uh-Nulty, which is how I was raised to pronounce it. The family pronunciation and mumbles of something about Scots-Irish as opposed to the Irish pronunciation explained this away to me as a child. (I didn't sign up to be born with this surname. I've had it all my life, so this is a kind of funny special interest to me.)

My grandfather would often write the name McAnulty with the c small and raised with an underscore. It's not merely decorative: it contains and explains the pronunciation, as Mc with the underscore is an abbreviation of Mac, hence the alphabetization of Mc between Mab and Mad in some older alphabetization systems.

Relevant links that have influenced my understanding:

- http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/Scotch-Irish/2000-01/0947887870
- http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/Scotch-Irish/2000-01/0947890937
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334927/moving-the-lower-case-c-up-above-type-in-the-last-name-mcneil

I'd like to produce this raised c with an underscore in LaTeX, but you can probably easily imagine and understand that, having grown up with this name and having seen it with the raised c with underscore in older handwriting and signs, I have particular aesthetic opinions about how the line under the c should look and the overall shape of the surname.

I've produced this:

[image: no underline]
using this code:

```
{\LARGE\scheader \textsc{dan m{\large\raisebox{0.35ex}{{\underline{\smash{c}}}}}{\kern 0.05pc a}nulty}}
```

and this:

[image: with underline]
using this:

```
{\LARGE\scheader \textsc{dan m{\large\raisebox{0.30ex}{c}}anulty}}
```

Neither quite match what I picture. The example images below depict the underline as more narrow than the letter, and ideally its right side should match up with the c's right-hand side. How I envision the correct way to raise and underline this c include:

[image: c with underline]

[image: c with underline in sign]

[image: mccormick logo]

While I can control the height and size of the c with my current code, and using the soul library I could control the closeness and thickness of the underline (see the [soul library example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50637/closer-underline)), I have not yet found a good means to control the width of the line under the letter.

I believe the underscore is called a [Macron below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron_below).

Does anybody have good recommendations for the right way to size up the underline to achieve these aesthetic ends in this situation?

I will appreciate any responses, thoughts, or suggestions.

Comment: Interesting. As a non-Scot, non-British, non-American, ... I was raised in the belief that Mc is an abbreviation for mac and never tried to pronounce mc differently from mac. This was re-enforced with the advent of McDonalds everywhere, also pronounced as Mac... But apparently there are more choices for English-speaking natives.

Comment: Quite often, in the states, people pronounce it Mick-Donalds, I think it's not a syllable that most americans give much thought to, and historically it is a bit unclear I think.  That's probably part of why I got so interested in this macron-below idea, it's something I remember clearly from growing up, and I think it be the only valid clue that an outside observer might get that could indicate a preference between Mac vs Mick.  Again, for me, it's never been a big deal, but if I have a means to write out the correct pronunciation of my own name, I ought to make an effort to use it, I figure.

Comment: Because the pronunciation is affected by stress (as well as regional/accent effects), this is quite an interesting topic.  It's been discussed in some depth at english.se: [*When does the name prefix “Mc” take stress?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73900/when-does-the-name-prefix-mc-take-stress).

Comment: @ChrisH which sugests the question: Do people in the states often pronounce the Apple product as MICKintosh ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I believe it's usually "MACintosh" to most English speakers in most places, but I'm in the UK. Besides I normally pronounce it "overpriced  junk".  I'm unsure about the use of a phonetic spelling of "Mick---" -- IME if it's not "Mack" the stress is on the next syllable and the vowel is a schwa ə (wikipedia uses the *a* of *about* as an example).  Here that's common for "McDonalds, for example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In my experience (Northeastern US), people pronounce it "MACKintosh", or just call them "MACKs". But I'd also note that the computer line is written "Macintosh".  The variety of apples (the fruit) **is** written "McIntosh", but pronounced the same way.

Comment: I can't cite chapter and verse, only local usage, but I've always taken there to be essentially free variation between ‘Mac[Dd]onald’, ‘Mc[Dd]onald’ and even (though this is now rare) ‘M’[Dd]onald’, with ‘M^cDonald’ being only a stylistic/typographic variation. People will tend to write their own family name in a consistent way, but there's no general rule. When alphabetising, such surnames are written in the preferred way, but alphabetised as if each of them started the same way: ‘mac’. If you're gaelic and male, however, then I believe the only possibility is ‘Mac Donald’ (ie, two words).

Comment: With a broad Scots accent you can pretty much say Mick or Mack at your discretion as you please.

Answer (score 46):

You can use a trick for discovering the script size. The box is raised by the difference of the height of the M and the height of the (reduced) c.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Mc}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mc}{%
  M%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`M-\height}{%
    \check@mathfonts\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont
    \underline{c}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Mc Anulty

\Large\Mc Anulty

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the output for

```
\textsc{\Mc Anulty}
```

[image]

An extended version where

1. the underline is slightly shorter
2. the macro also works with `\MakeUppercase`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mc}{\Mcx{c}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MC}{\Mcx{\textsc{c}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mcx}[1]{%
  M%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`M-\height}{%
    \check@mathfonts\fontsize{\sf@size}{0}\selectfont
    \kern.1ex\underline{\kern-.1ex #1\kern-.1ex}\kern.1ex
  }%
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\@uclclist\expandafter{%
  \@uclclist\Mc\MC
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Mc Anulty \textsc{\Mc Anulty} \MakeUppercase{\Mc Anulty}

\Large \Mc Anulty

\end{document}
```

[image: Extended]

Yet another version with `ulem` (I can't recommend `soul` for this application).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Mc}{%
  M%
  \raisebox{\depth}{%
    \check@mathfonts\fontsize{\sf@size}{\sf@size}\selectfont
    \kern.3ex \uline{\kern-.3ex C\kern-.2ex}\kern.2ex
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Mc Anulty \textsc{\Mc Anulty} \MakeUppercase{\Mc Anulty}

\Large \Mc Anulty

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, those are both very aesthetically appealing.  I will have to work to understand the code, as it's not immediately obvious to me yet.

Would this work with small caps as well?

Comment: The forum is still fighting me like crazy because I just signed up for it, but this was one of my examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfCkS.png

Comment: That I'd achieved.  

This was one of my failures, you can see the line is too wide:  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LocRO.png

Comment: This, lastly, is a real typographic ideal, would be very nice to be able to accomplish this, or also the McCORMICK example in the post:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdKqQ.png

Comment: The other helper links that should have gone into the post (and were edited out, as were my placeholders, making the question much clearer but at the same time masking my original structure) were:
http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/Scotch-Irish/2000-01/0947887870
http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/Scotch-Irish/2000-01/0947890937
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334927/moving-the-lower-case-c-up-above-type-in-the-last-name-mcneil

Comment: And here for an example of the soul library: 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50637/closer-underline

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this. I'm the secretary for a Hibernian society, mostly full of old fellers (except me). A particular McDonald was rather happy to see his name like this, as he remembers from a long time ago.

Answer (score 32):

The salient points of this approach

1. The c is top aligned to the height of the M, while the underscore sits on the baseline (this was apparent in the OP's provided `McCormick` image)
2. The thickness of the underbar can be provided as an optional parameter
3. I kept the small c at the nominal size, but changing the `1` in the `\scalebox` could alter that to suit.
4. I made the width of the underscore 70% of the `c` width.  I also `\kern`ed the underscore slightly to the right, to accommodate the asymmetric sidebearings of the letter  `c`.
5. The `\Mc` macro will change to suit the current font size and style.

Here is the MWE (optional argument employed on the 2nd instance).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\Mc[1][.17ex]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\scalebox{1}{c}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{M}%
  M\stackengine{0pt}{\kern.07\wd0\rule{.7\wd0}{#1}}{\belowbaseline[-\ht2]{\copy0}}%
    {O}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}

\begin{document}
\Mc CORMICK

\LARGE\Mc[.13ex]CORMICK

\sffamily

\Mc CORMICK

\normalsize \Mc CORMICK
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ALTERNATIVE APPROACH**

Here, the underscore does not sit on the baseline, but at a prescribed gap below the `c`.  Other changes are the size of the `c` has been reduced to 70%; the thickness of the underscore reduced to `.13ex`; the optional argument specifies the gap between `c` and underscore (applied in the 2nd instance)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\Mc[1][.13ex]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{c}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{M}%
  M\stackengine{\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2+#1}{\belowbaseline[-\ht2]{\copy0}}%
    {\kern.07\wd0\rule[-.13ex]{.7\wd0}{.13ex}}%
    {U}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}

\begin{document}
\Mc CORMICK

\LARGE\Mc[.3ex]CORMICK

\sffamily

\Mc CORMICK

\normalsize \Mc CORMICK
\end{document}
```

[image]

**APPROACH 3**

This attempts to achieve the edit of the OP, in which the height of the `c` is not set to the top of the M, but perhaps a serif thickness below the top.

So what I do is make the thickness of the underscore the value of the optional argument (default `.12ex`, which should be set to the serif thickness for a serif font, or the stroke thickness for a sans serif font), and also decline the `C` from the top of the line by the same amount.  Further, I use a capital, rather than lowercase `C`, unlike my earlier excursions.  Lastly, I have revised the width of the underscore based on the framing lines provided by the OP in the close-up image.  In addition to right-aligning the underscore,  I estimated the sidebearings of the `C` to be 7% of the letter width, and therefore made the width of the underscore equal to 86% of the `C` width (accounting for the sidebearings) minus the serif width provided as the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\Mc[1][.12ex]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{C}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{M}%
  M\stackengine{0pt}{\rule{\dimexpr.86\wd0-#1}{#1}\kern.07\wd0}%
    {\belowbaseline[\dimexpr-\ht2+#1]{\copy0}}%
    {O}{r}{F}{F}{L}%
}

\begin{document}
\Mc[.08ex]CORMICK

\LARGE\Mc[.08ex]CORMICK

\sffamily

\Mc CORMICK

\normalsize \Mc CORMICK
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The result looks nice and the OP finally decide, but I question the assumption that `the underscore sits on the baseline (this was apparent in the OP's provided images)`. For me it is quite apparent from the images that the underscore *does not* sit on the baseline. In fact, when looking at [other abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript#Superscripts_that_typically_do_not_extend_above_the_ascender_line) the underscore is rather underlining the c.

Comment: I think both methods are potentially important to have access to in different situations, like if you look at this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdKqQ.png
It's clearly on the baseline, but this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3MYb.jpg
they're floating it up.

I remember my family more often floating the underscore off the baseline, but I can also admire the aesthetic choice of keeping it low and even.  It seems to me that both methods could be appropriate to users of this diacritical mark, so I hoped both methods would be illustrated if possible. I think the two responders have done.

Comment: @gernot On the `McMaster` photograph, I think you are right, but on the `McCormick` logo, I do think it sits there.

Comment: You are right regarding McCormick, but I wouldn't trust a logo when it comes to typography.

Comment: @DanMcAnulty See my approach #3, which tries to address your later edit, depicting the framing lines.

Comment: The lowercase "c" in the otherwise uppercase examples looks a bit odd to me (in a serif font).  Was this a deliberate choice that I irrationally dislike, or perhaps something akin to a typo? The examples under approach 3 look much better.  I've now seen where you make that change.

Answer (score 13):

A simple solution with `\textsuperscript`and `soulutf8`. I define a `\Mc` command with one optional argument for the height adjustment of the `c` superscript, and a mandatory argument, the variable part of the name.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{soulutf8}
\newcommand\Mc[2][-0.6\depth]{\setul{0.25ex}{0.08ex}\setuloverlap{-0.08em}M\textsuperscript{\raisebox{#1}{\ul{c}}}#2}

\begin{document}

{\LARGE\textsc{dan \Mc{Anulty}}} \vspace{1cm}

{\normalsize\textsc{dan \Mc[0pt]{Anulty}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One for ConTeXt users:

```
%\setupbodyfont[pagella]
%\setupbodyfont[scholas]
\setupbodyfont[termes]

\starttext
  \newbox\MacMBox
  \setbox\MacMBox\hbox{M}
  \newbox\MacCBox
  \setbox\MacCBox\hbox{c}
  \newbox\MacKernBox
  \setbox\MacKernBox\hbox{\inframed[offset=\zeropoint, width=fit]{Mc}}

  \def\MacDelta{\dimexpr\wd\MacKernBox-\wd\MacMBox-\wd\MacCBox\relax}
  \def\MacUWidth{\dimexpr\wd\MacCBox-.75\MacDelta\relax}
  \def\MacRule{\vrule width \MacUWidth height .05em depth \zeropoint \relax}
  \def\MacKern{\dimexpr\wd\MacKernBox-\wd\MacMBox-\wd\MacCBox\relax}

  \def\Mac{%
    M{%
      \dontleavehmode{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\MacMBox-\ht\MacCBox}\hbox{c}}%
      \kern-1.04\MacUWidth
      \MacRule
      \kern.08\MacUWidth
    }%
  }

  \scale[scale=5000]{\Mac Anulty}
  \Mac Anulty
\stoptext
```

[image: C with Macron]