# To make the numero sign, would N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}} be a valid alternative to \textnumero (from textcomp package)

Tags: symbols, superscripts

Regarding [LaTeX: Numero sign ('№')](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40564/latex-numero-sign), 
would

```
N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}}
```

be a valid alternative to \textnumero (from textcomp package)? I prefer a numero sign that matches the font used for the surrounding text, although this is apparently not the preference of some fontographers (see Times New Roman).

Comment: Which font do you use?

Comment: Though this might be an abuse of `\b`, `N\textsuperscript{\b{o}}` might also be a valid alternative.

Comment: `textcomp` doesn't provide any symbols itself. The symbol shown there is not from the package. Rather, the package is providing access to the symbol in the currently active font. (At least, it will do this where a suitable font exists. I'm not sure what exactly it does if there's no font available at all. Probably then it will fall back to Computer Modern.)

Comment: The discussion on the Irish "Mc" may be relevant here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364024/scots-irish-american-surnames-mc-how-to-achieve-a-range-of-aesthetically-appe

Comment: In answer to the question of @bernard, I have been using Computer Modern (or the version provided by fix-cm). Sometimes Adobe Times or Adobe Helvetica (`\fontfamily{ptm}...`).

Answer (score 6):

Taking a lead from the **ALTERNATIVE APPROACH** in my answer at [Scots-Irish American surnames: Mc - how to achieve a range of aesthetically appealing raised-c with underscore?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364024/scots-irish-american-surnames-mc-how-to-achieve-a-range-of-aesthetically-appe/364028#364028)...

The optional argument sets the gap between the "o" and underscore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\No[1][.13ex]{%
  \setbox0=\hbox{\scalebox{.7}{o}}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{N}%
  N\kern-.05em\stackengine{\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2+#1}{\belowbaseline[-\ht2]{\copy0}}%
    {\rule[-.13ex]{.7\wd0}{.13ex}}%
    {U}{c}{F}{F}{L}%
}

\begin{document}
\No 3

\LARGE\No[.2ex]3

\sffamily

\No 3

\normalsize \No 3
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. Note that (as I've just discovered), loading `\usepackage[french]{babel}` will lead to a conflict since that defines a `\No` command already. Presumably many users of babel/french would know that, but I'm quite ignorant.

Comment: Thank you, @PatrickT, for noting that conflict, which was unknown to me.  Obviously, the solution is to give the macro a different name.

Comment: Indeed I went for `\Numero`  :-)

Answer (score 3):

`textcomp` just takes glyph 155 (octal 233) from TS1 in computer modern, which gives the symbol you don't like.

See e.g. [the LaTeX font encodings document](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf); the relevant page is below.

[image]

And no, I don't have any objection to your choice, but as cfr observes, this glyph *is* part of the font.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the comment, showing the plain, manually-constructed, form in blue (without any additional kerning, raiseboxes etc), to compare against the font designer's version:

[image: fonts]

Legacy fonts would require much more work (TS1 vs T1 encodings, kerning, resizes, etc):

[image: fonts legacy]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\nhead{\rowcolor{blue!12}}
\newcommand\propsol{{\color{blue}N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}}}}
\newcommand\legpropsol{{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}\color{blue}[N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}}]}}
\newcommand\mytext{text № [\propsol] 3 text}
\newfontfamily\ffonta{Book Antiqua}
%\newfontfamily\ffontb{Commissioner-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\ffontc{Cormorant Garamond}
\newfontfamily\ffontd{Cormorant Infant}
\newfontfamily\ffonte{Cormorant SC}
\newfontfamily\ffontf{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontg{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonth{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffonti{Doulos SIL}
%\newfontfamily\ffontj{Exo 2}
\newfontfamily\ffontk{FreeMono}
\newfontfamily\ffontl{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\ffontm{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\ffontn{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily\ffonto{IBM Plex Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffontp{IBM Plex Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontq{IBM Plex Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontr{Liberation Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonts{Liberation Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontt{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontu{Linux Biolinum G}
\newfontfamily\ffontv{Linux Libertine Display G}
\newfontfamily\ffontw{Linux Libertine G}
\newfontfamily\ffontx{Noto Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonty{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontz{Noto Sans Display}
\newfontfamily\ffontaa{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontab{Noto Serif Display}
\newfontfamily\ffontac{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\ffontad{Source Code Pro}
\newfontfamily\ffontae{Source Sans Pro}
\newfontfamily\ffontaf{Source Serif Pro}

\newcommand\legfont[2]{%
\usefont{T1}{#1}{m}{#2}text \usefont{TS1}{#1}{m}{#2}\char"9B  \legpropsol \usefont{T1}{#1}{m}{#2}\ 3 text
}

\begin{document}

Unicode glyph [plus manually constructed form]

U+2116 № [\verb|N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}}|]

\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lll}
\nhead Font & Upright & Italic \\
Book Antiqua & \ffonta\mytext & \ffonta\textit{\mytext} \\
%Commissioner & \ffontb\mytext & \ffontb\textit{\mytext} \\
Cormorant Garamond & \ffontc\mytext & \ffontc\textit{\mytext} \\
Cormorant Infant &  & \ffontd\textit{\mytext} \\
%Cormorant SC & \ffonte\mytext & \\
DejaVu Sans & \ffontf\mytext & \ffontf\textit{\mytext} \\
DejaVu Sans Mono & \ffontg\mytext & \ffontg\textit{\mytext} \\
DejaVu Serif & \ffonth\mytext & \ffonth\textit{\mytext} \\
Doulos SIL & \ffonti\mytext &  \\
%Exo 2 & \ffontj\mytext & \ffontj\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeMono & \ffontk\mytext & \ffontk\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeSans & \ffontl\mytext & \ffontl\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeSerif & \ffontm\mytext & \ffontm\textit{\mytext} \\
Gentium Plus & \ffontn\mytext & \ffontn\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Mono & \ffonto\mytext & \ffonto\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Sans & \ffontp\mytext & \ffontp\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Serif & \ffontq\mytext & \ffontq\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Mono & \ffontr\mytext & \ffontr\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Sans & \ffonts\mytext & \ffonts\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Serif & \ffontt\mytext & \ffontt\textit{\mytext} \\
Linux Biolinum G & \ffontu\mytext & \ffontu\textit{\mytext} \\
Linux Libertine Display G & \ffontv\mytext & \\
Linux Libertine G & \ffontw\mytext & \ffontw\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Mono & \ffontx\mytext &  \\
Noto Sans & \ffonty\mytext & \ffonty\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Sans Display & \ffontz\mytext & \ffontz\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Serif & \ffontaa\mytext & \ffontaa\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Serif Display & \ffontab\mytext & \ffontab\textit{\mytext} \\
Roboto & \ffontac\mytext & \ffontac\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Code Pro & \ffontad\mytext & \ffontad\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Sans Pro & \ffontae\mytext & \ffontae\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Serif Pro & \ffontaf\mytext &  \\

\end{tabular}

\newpage
\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}Legacy fonts: slot 9B of TS1 encoding:  {\usefont{TS1}{lmr}{m}{n}\char"9B}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\nhead Font family & Upright & Italic \\
lmr & \legfont{lmr}{n} & \legfont{lmr}{it} \\
qzc &  & \legfont{qzc}{it} \\
qtm & \legfont{qtm}{n} & \legfont{qtm}{it} \\
qpl & \legfont{qpl}{n} & \legfont{qpl}{it} \\
qhv & \legfont{qhv}{n} & \legfont{qhv}{it} \\
qcs & \legfont{qcs}{n} & \legfont{qcs}{it} \\
qcr & \legfont{qcr}{n} & \legfont{qcr}{it} \\
qbk & \legfont{qbk}{n} & \legfont{qbk}{it} \\
qag & \legfont{qag}{n} & \legfont{qag}{it} \\
stix2 & \legfont{stix2}{n} & \legfont{stix2}{it} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

*Original answer*

The abbreviation for *numero* seems to be like ℜ ℞ ℃ Å ℮ ℅ ℊ, in the sense of having its own typesetting tradition, which means that making it match the surrounding text could surprise some readers.

Having said that, it is a rarely used glyph and does seem to have some free-form quality about it, almost exotic, in terms of being a little bit different from the surroundings (especially in the serif fonts) but not too different.

Unicode font sample:

[image: unicode]

Legacy font sample:

[image: legacy font]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\nhead{\rowcolor{blue!12}}
\newcommand\mytext{text № 3 text}
\newfontfamily\ffonta{Book Antiqua}
%\newfontfamily\ffontb{Commissioner-Regular.ttf}
\newfontfamily\ffontc{Cormorant Garamond}
\newfontfamily\ffontd{Cormorant Infant}
\newfontfamily\ffonte{Cormorant SC}
\newfontfamily\ffontf{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontg{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonth{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffonti{Doulos SIL}
%\newfontfamily\ffontj{Exo 2}
\newfontfamily\ffontk{FreeMono}
\newfontfamily\ffontl{FreeSans}
\newfontfamily\ffontm{FreeSerif}
\newfontfamily\ffontn{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily\ffonto{IBM Plex Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffontp{IBM Plex Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontq{IBM Plex Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontr{Liberation Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonts{Liberation Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontt{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontu{Linux Biolinum G}
\newfontfamily\ffontv{Linux Libertine Display G}
\newfontfamily\ffontw{Linux Libertine G}
\newfontfamily\ffontx{Noto Mono}
\newfontfamily\ffonty{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily\ffontz{Noto Sans Display}
\newfontfamily\ffontaa{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\ffontab{Noto Serif Display}
\newfontfamily\ffontac{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\ffontad{Source Code Pro}
\newfontfamily\ffontae{Source Sans Pro}
\newfontfamily\ffontaf{Source Serif Pro}

\newcommand\legfont[2]{%
\usefont{T1}{#1}{m}{#2}text \usefont{TS1}{#1}{m}{#2}\char"9B\usefont{T1}{#1}{m}{#2}\ 3 text
}

\begin{document}

U+2116 №

\bigskip
\noindent\begin{tabular}{lll}
\nhead Font & Upright & Italic \\
Book Antiqua & \ffonta\mytext & \ffonta\textit{\mytext} \\
%Commissioner & \ffontb\mytext & \ffontb\textit{\mytext} \\
Cormorant Garamond & \ffontc\mytext & \ffontc\textit{\mytext} \\
Cormorant Infant &  & \ffontd\textit{\mytext} \\
%Cormorant SC & \ffonte\mytext & \\
DejaVu Sans & \ffontf\mytext & \ffontf\textit{\mytext} \\
DejaVu Sans Mono & \ffontg\mytext & \ffontg\textit{\mytext} \\
DejaVu Serif & \ffonth\mytext & \ffonth\textit{\mytext} \\
Doulos SIL & \ffonti\mytext &  \\
%Exo 2 & \ffontj\mytext & \ffontj\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeMono & \ffontk\mytext & \ffontk\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeSans & \ffontl\mytext & \ffontl\textit{\mytext} \\
FreeSerif & \ffontm\mytext & \ffontm\textit{\mytext} \\
Gentium Plus & \ffontn\mytext & \ffontn\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Mono & \ffonto\mytext & \ffonto\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Sans & \ffontp\mytext & \ffontp\textit{\mytext} \\
IBM Plex Serif & \ffontq\mytext & \ffontq\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Mono & \ffontr\mytext & \ffontr\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Sans & \ffonts\mytext & \ffonts\textit{\mytext} \\
Liberation Serif & \ffontt\mytext & \ffontt\textit{\mytext} \\
Linux Biolinum G & \ffontu\mytext & \ffontu\textit{\mytext} \\
Linux Libertine Display G & \ffontv\mytext & \\
Linux Libertine G & \ffontw\mytext & \ffontw\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Mono & \ffontx\mytext &  \\
Noto Sans & \ffonty\mytext & \ffonty\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Sans Display & \ffontz\mytext & \ffontz\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Serif & \ffontaa\mytext & \ffontaa\textit{\mytext} \\
Noto Serif Display & \ffontab\mytext & \ffontab\textit{\mytext} \\
Roboto & \ffontac\mytext & \ffontac\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Code Pro & \ffontad\mytext & \ffontad\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Sans Pro & \ffontae\mytext & \ffontae\textit{\mytext} \\
Source Serif Pro & \ffontaf\mytext &  \\

\end{tabular}

\newpage
\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}Legacy fonts: slot 9B of TS1 encoding:  {\usefont{TS1}{lmr}{m}{n}\char"9B}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\nhead Font family & Upright & Italic \\
lmr & \legfont{lmr}{n} & \legfont{lmr}{it} \\
qzc &  & \legfont{qzc}{it} \\
qtm & \legfont{qtm}{n} & \legfont{qtm}{it} \\
qpl & \legfont{qpl}{n} & \legfont{qpl}{it} \\
qhv & \legfont{qhv}{n} & \legfont{qhv}{it} \\
qcs & \legfont{qcs}{n} & \legfont{qcs}{it} \\
qcr & \legfont{qcr}{n} & \legfont{qcr}{it} \\
qbk & \legfont{qbk}{n} & \legfont{qbk}{it} \\
qag & \legfont{qag}{n} & \legfont{qag}{it} \\
stix2 & \legfont{stix2}{n} & \legfont{stix2}{it} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Re: "it is a rarely used glyph:" Perhaps in English. Russian typewriters have a special "numero" key, though. See also this [computer keyboard layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdru1.html)

Comment: Nice table. Could you add a column that shows what my proposed solution (`N\textsuperscript{\underline{\scriptsize o}}`) would look like in each of the fonts?

Comment: See amended answer. (`Numero` is one glyph in the fonts, like `$`, so the manually constructed form, two glyphs, looks a bit odd in some places; on the other hand, some font designers don't make it as much calligraphic as it is supposed to be, so closer to the manual shape.)

Comment: Yes. It used to be above 3, where `#` is now, on American English typewriters; English English ones had `￡` in that position, which is why some people still call `#` "pound (sign)".

Comment: Correction: keyboard/key layout was different for each model and manufacturer, so everyone's experience will vary. Typewriters were the mechanical equivalent of a font file before Unicode. :)