# Numero sign (№) not displaying correctly

Tags: xetex

Why every text numero symbol has replaced with symbol on the fugure below?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\begin{document}
№
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.11.29)  30 NOV 2018 07:41
entering extended mode
**./document.tex
(document.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty"
Package: polyglossia 2018/04/07 v1.43 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaL
aTeX


(C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count88
)
(C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\makecmds\makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count89
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
(C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.st
y (C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-11-19 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-11-19 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count90
\l_tmpa_int=\count91
\l_tmpb_int=\count92
\g_tmpa_int=\count93
\g_tmpb_int=\count94
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count95
\c_log_iow=\count96
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
\l__iow_indent_int=\count100
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count101
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count102
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
\g__intarray_font_int=\count103
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count110
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count111
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count112
\g__fp_array_int=\count113
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count114
\l__sort_length_int=\count115
\l__sort_min_int=\count116
\l__sort_top_int=\count117
\l__sort_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count119
\l__sort_block_int=\count120
\l__sort_begin_int=\count121
\l__sort_end_int=\count122
\l__sort_A_int=\count123
\l__sort_B_int=\count124
\l__sort_C_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count128
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count131
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count132
\l__regex_balance_int=\count133
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count134
\l__regex_mode_int=\count135
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count136
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count137
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count138
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count142
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count143
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count144
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count145
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count149
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count150
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count156
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count157
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count159
\l__regex_step_int=\count160
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count161
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count163
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count164
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count165
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count167
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count168
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen127
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen134
)
(C:\Users\work\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2018-11-19 v L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\g__driver_image_int=\count169
\g__driver_pdf_object_int=\count170
))
Package: xparse 2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count171
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count172
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count173
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count174
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count175
)
Package: fontspec 2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2018/07/30 vv2.6h Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaT
eX
\l__fontspec_script_int=\count176
\l__fontspec_language_int=\count177
\l__fontspec_strnum_int=\count178
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count179
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count180
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count181
\l__fontspec_strong_int=\count182
\l__fontspec_strongdef_int=\count183
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen136
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen137

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\tuenc.def"
File: tuenc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding TU on input line 82.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 3910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 3915.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 3920.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 3925.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 3955.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 3980.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 4034.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\xpg@normalclass=\XeTeXcharclass1
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\gloss-russian.ldf"
File: gloss-russian.ldf polyglossia: module for russian

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\polyglossia\babelsh.def"
File: babelsh.def 2013/04/30 Babel common definitions for shorthands
 Taken verbatim from babel.def (2013/04/15 v3.9e)
)
Package polyglossia Info: Making " an active character on input line 41.
)
Package polyglossia Info: Default language is russian.

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'CMUSerif(0)' created for font 'CMU Serif'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures=TeX].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"

(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 

LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 7.

(document.aux

Package fontspec Info: Font family 'CMUSerif(1)' created for font 'CMU Serif'
(fontspec)             with options [Ligatures=TeX,Script=Cyrillic].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/OT:script=cyrl;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/B/OT:script=cyrl;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/I/OT:script=cyrl;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"CMU
(fontspec)             Serif/BI/OT:script=cyrl;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"

(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: 

)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n on input line
 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/CMUSerif(0)/m/n --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/bx/n on input lin
e 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> TU/CMUSerif(0)/bx/it on input line 7.

LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> TU/lmss/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/bx/n on input line 7.
Missing character: There is no № in font CMU Serif Roman/OT:script=cyrl;languag
e=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;!
 [1

] (document.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 12283 strings out of 427796
 263439 string characters out of 3151768
 346175 words of memory out of 3000000
 16278 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532418 words of font info for 34 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,4n,67p,829b,443s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on document.pdf (1 page).
```

**UPD: Full reinstallation of font CMU helped.**

Comment: Does it work if you use another font, for example `Arial`?

Comment: My guess would be that the font you are using just does not contain a symbol for `№`

Comment: It works correctly with Verdana and Arial

Comment: If your font does not contain this symbol, you can create it yourself: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375962/36296

Comment: Ok, I'll try this. But a week ago the numero sign was in my docs in CMU Serif font.

Comment: You need to use a font that provides the glyph you wish to reproduce. Some serif fonts that provide this glyph (as well as Cyrillic glyphs) are EB Garamond, Garamond Premier Pro, and Minion Pro. Some sans-serif fonts that feature this symbol are Arial and Myriad Pro. In contrast, neither CMU Serif nor CMU Sans Serif would appear to feature a `№` glyph.

Comment: @Mico I'm not sure what version of CMU Serif you're referring to. The one on CTAN and in TeX Live has the glyph.

Comment: @egreg - Very interesting. I got my version from https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/cmu-serif. Version 0.7.0, year 2009.

Comment: @Mico The very same I have; and it *does* have U+2116 NUMERO SIGN.

Comment: @egreg - This is getting weird: The OP's MWE generates the crossed-out box symbol when compiled with XeLaTeX -- and the `№` glyph when compiled with LuaLaTeX. (I use MacTeX2018.)

Comment: @Mico I get the glyph in both cases. That's why I asked for the log file. But probably more thorough investigation is necessary.

Comment: @VasyaPravdin From the log file it seems that you have a bogus CMU Serif font on your system.

Comment: That's deep. Full reinstallation of fonts helped. Thank you!

Comment: I will close the question as no answer is needed or useful anymore, since it was solved be reinstalling fonts as stated in the comments.