# Saint abbreviation

Tags: xetex, typography, french

I would like to know if there is a way to abbreviate "saint" in this french way. A dash is also commonly used.

[image]

My researches are unsuccessful at this point, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a standard abbreviation and is used just for street signs, as far as I know. Did you find in other texts?

Comment: Okay did not know that. I don't think so, mainly on street sign yes. I really like the way it look compare to a simple St. I should not use it in a french document?

Comment: Peripherally related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364024/scots-irish-american-surnames-mc-how-to-achieve-a-range-of-aesthetically-appe

Comment: Normally, this adjective should not be abbreviated in French, except occasionally if you're lacking space.

Comment: Leaving aside why this was 'abbreviated' in the first place (perhaps this rule is English language only, and not French) ... but in general, "St" is **not** an abbreviation, but a _contraction_ for the word "Saint". This means it should not have a 'dot' at all in the first place, i.e. St Germain. Compare to "Street", which _is_ an abbreviation, e.g.: "St George St.". The same goes with other contractions vs abbreviations, e.g. "Dr Jekyll" but "Prof. Hyde".

Comment: As egreg stated it, the proper way to write it in French is Saint-Germain, eventually St-Germain. No dot at all.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou That depends on your culture. Americans (and Canadians?) put periods after contractions ("Dr.") where Brits do not.

Comment: @AzorAhai I would argue it's not a cultural thing, but simply that grammatically speaking it's a form of hypercorrection that seems to have established itself by common use, much like like "virii" or "expresso". In a sense, using the hypercorrected variant is fine in an informal context, but given a choice, personally I would always go for the grammatically correct version. This is in contrast to purely orthographic established deviations between UK and US english (e.g. centre vs center / advise vs advize ... though I suppose one could argue those started as hypercorrections the same way ...)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou No, a period on the end of "Dr" or not is not a grammatical feature. There is no "grammatically correct version." One option is correct in the UK and one is correct in the US.

Comment: @AzorAhai hm, you're right. Interesting. Seems like in the UK, the Oxford dictionary prescribes no period as the preferred way of writing contractions, whereas in US professional writing the convention (presumably due to common use variability) is to follow their institution's preferred manual of style (e.g. some style manuals, like the Chicago Manual of Style, prescribe periods, whereas others, like the Modern Language Association style manual, prescribe their omission). Whereas I had thought the use of periods was more of a common use artefact. Good to know it's more established than that.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou I've never seen an American omit the period in any sort of writing, in newspapers, literature, scientific, etc. Was not aware the MLA suggests not using it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following should produce what you want. You can use an optional argument to specify another letter than `T` (e.g. `t`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newsavebox\myboxA
\newsavebox\myboxB
\newcommand\saint[1][T]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \sbox\myboxA{S}%
    \usebox\myboxA
    \sbox\myboxB{\tiny#1}%
    \rlap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\myboxA-\ht\myboxB}{\usebox\myboxB}}%
    \makebox[\wd\myboxB]{.}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\saint\ Germain
\saint[t] Germain
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libre Bodoni}

\NewDocumentCommand{\frabbr}{sm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\dofrabbr{}{#2}}{\dofrabbr{\hfil}{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\dofrabbr}[2]{%
  \vbox to\fontcharht\font`T {%
    \ialign{%
      #1##\hfil\cr
      \relscriptsize#2\cr
      \noalign{\nointerlineskip\vfill}
      .\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\relscriptsize}{%
  \check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@\selectfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
6\frabbr*{me} Arr\frabbr{T} \\
BOULEVARD \\
S\frabbr{T} GERMAIN
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]