# underlining of a text depends on the text

Tags: underline

When I want to underline text, I have a gap depending on whether the text contains letters that go down or not.
For example :

```
    
    \begin{document}
Je teste le \underline{soulignement} \underline{avec} ou sans lettres qui descendent
    \end{document}
```

[image]

How to line up the underline or to "cut" the underline for the letters going down?

Comment: You might find some help here: [underline omitting the descenders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36894)

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50637/closer-underline for an approach with the `soul` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\uline` from the `ulem` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document}
Je teste le \underline{soulignement} \underline{avec} ou sans lettres qui descendent

Je teste le \uline{soulignement} \uline{avec} ou sans lettres qui descendent
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]