# set paragraph headings in colour

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I am trying to get my paragraph headings to be in color, so I try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{gentium,color,titlesec}
\definecolor{tuftsblue}{rgb}{0.08, 0.37, 0.61}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{tuftsblue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{tuftsblue}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{tuftsblue}}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\color{{tuftsblue}{paragraph}}}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Minimum Working Example}
\paragraph{Lipsum 1} \lipsum[1]
\paragraph{Lipsum 2} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

However, I do not get them in color? I also tried:

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{tuftsblue}}{\theparagraph}{0em}{}
```

but then I get a linebreak after the paragraph title.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the optional "shape" option to `\titleformat`, as explained its the [titlesec documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), page 3. You most likely want to specify the "runin" shape, which is default for `\paragraph` to avoid the linebreak.

```
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{tuftsblue}}{}{0em}{}
```

[image: colored paragraph headings]

Redefining the command `\theparagraph` would only format paragraph *numbers* if you were using a counter for them, but numbers are not used by default for paragraphs.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! Btw, how do I underline the paragraph heading?

Comment: You could put `\underline` in the last argument to `\titleformat` (change `{}` to `{\underline}`, or better yet, load the `soul` package and use `{\ul}`, which would allow you more fine grained control as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50637/closer-underline); I think the default is too low to look good.

Comment: Thanks for this and also the link! Sorry, one more question, can I have a uniform symbol after the underline then? For instance, a colon at the end of the paragraph heading, but the underline does not include the colon.

Comment: You could use the final optional argument `[:]` at the very end of the `\titleformat` command (*after* `{\ul}`). You should consider reading the package documentation for yourself, so you're familiar with all the options.