# Why doesn't \underline{REALLY LONG TEXT} wrap?

Tags: line-breaking, text-decorations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does underlined text not get wrapped once it hits the end of a line ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9550/why-does-underlined-text-not-get-wrapped-once-it-hits-the-end-of-a-line)

The string `\underline{FOO BAR FOO BAR FOO BAR ... [100 more of these]}` runs off the page in my compiled pdf. How can I make it wrap?

Comment: underlining is not a good typography. Can you do something else to mark it, for example using an italic font, typewriter font, etc.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31566/is-it-possible-to-have-hyphenations-in-underlinedtext

Comment: Thank you. Why isn't underlining good typography?